# Can rake db:create create tables in multiple databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Can I create tables in two databases using `db:create`? For example, can I have entries in `database.yml` for `one_development` and `two_development` and have both get created by `rake db:create`? I know rake db:create:all works -- I am just wondering if there is a way to segment what is created depending on the RAILS_ENV?

Answer (score 6):

For **one_development** you can execute this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=one_development rake db:create
```

For **two_development** you can execute this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=two_development rake db:create
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the rake task or create a new one, which runs `rake db:create` for two environments that you need.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to do all the datasets automatically.  See the source:

http://dev.rubyonrails.org/changeset/6849

It does not appear to uses RAILS_ENV like drop, etc.